# Reverse Engineering a C# Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reverse-engineering, visio, diagramming

I know Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate has some abilities, and I would normally do this by instinct, but I am on a very tight schedule.  I also have Visio 2010 installed and integrated into VS, but its reverse engineer function doesn't seem to do much, and has to be run on a per project basis, and a hindrance here is the solution structure, with several solution folders each holding a multitude of projects.

I would like some advice on how to go about reverse engineering a C# solution into dependency diagrams, sequence diagrams and class diagrams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio, the 2010 Ultimate edition supports 5 commonly-used [UML diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409436.aspx) ([class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409437.aspx) , [sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409377.aspx) , [use case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409377.aspx) , [activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409377.aspx) , and [component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409390.aspx) ). You can [generate sequence diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409436.aspx) and [layer diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409436.aspx) from code . If you also install the [Visualization & Modeling Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460723.aspx) with VS 2010 Ultimate, you can [create UML class diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx) from code and [generate code from UML class diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx) .

You can also [explore existing code by using Architecture Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx) and [visualize relationships in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847415.aspx) by generating dependency graphs , which you can then also use to create layer diagrams.

As alternative, you can use [Altova Usemodel](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-reverse-engineering.html) or [Sparx System's Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/software_development/codeengineering.html)

Answer (score 1):

since C# is using JIT compilation, an intermediate code is generated in compilation and there is a way to see that intermediate code.

[reverse engineering in  C#](http://anilbey.blogspot.com/2013/12/reverse-engineering-in-net.html)

Comment: In this scenario, seeing the IL code is no different from seeing the C# code, which I said in my question I have.

Answer (score 0):

This tip is from : http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/30046
I am just pasting here. You should give credit to the original author if he is on StacOverflow

Open a window in VS.NET. Go to Project—>Visio UML—>Reverse Engineer. This automatically shows you the class diagrams with perfect relationships.
Note: This tip will work with VS.NET Version 1.0.0 and higher.